# My rails form is not being submitted or redirected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My invite form is not being saved. There are no errors. The mailer is not being sent and I am not being redirected to the root path.

Invites Controller:

```
class InvitesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @invite = Invite.new
  end

  def create
    @invite = Invite.new(invite_params)
    if @invite.save
      InviteMailer.invite_user(@invite).deliver_now
      flash[:success] = "You have successfully sent an invite"
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private

    def invite_params
      params.require(:invite).permit(:email)
    end
end
```

Invites Model:

```
class Invite < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Invites new View:

```
<h1>Invite your friend!</h1>
<%= form_for @invite , :url => userinvite_path do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :email %>
    <%= f.email_field :email %>
    <%= f.submit "Send" %>
<% end %>
```

Invites Mailer:

```
class InviteMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def invite_user(invite)
    @invite = invite
    mail to: invite.email, subject: "Invitation to Math-Scientist"
  end
end
```

Application Mailer:

```
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: 'noreply@example.com'
  layout 'mailer'
end
```

Mailer View (Text):
    Hi,
    You have been invited to join Math-Scientist by your friend.
    Sign up now: https://math-scientist.herokuapp.com/usersignup
    Hope you enjoy our product!

Routes File:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'static_pages#home'
  get '/usersignup', to: 'users#new'
  get '/companysignup', to: 'companies#new'
  get    '/userlogin',   to: 'sessions#new'
  post   '/userlogin',   to: 'sessions#create'
  delete '/userlogout',  to: 'sessions#destroy'
  get '/userinvite', to: 'invites#new'
  post '/userinvite', to: "invites#create"
  resources :users
  resources :companies
  resources :invites
end
```

Comment: There must be something wrong with your models. I suspect a rollback due to models relation. Have you checked your server log to see if there is any rollback actually happening? Cause if it does, then the `if @invite.save` gets `false` and you should be redirected back to `new`.

Comment: I removed the model association between invites and users because i did not really need it. This time the form was submitted and i was redirected but the mailer still was not sent.

Comment: Do you know, how to use `pry`? 
Add `gem 'pry'` to your Gemfile. And the add `binding.pry` after `else` in your controller. then run your test and watch the console. Then you can inspect `@invite.errors`.

Comment: This is my production.rb file:config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  host = 'math-scientist.herokuapp.com'
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: host }
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :address        => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
    :port           => '587',
    :authentication => :plain,
    :user_name      => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
    :password       => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
    :domain         => 'heroku.com',
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }

Comment: you are loading your *sendgrid credentials* as `ENV` variables. Have you added them to Heroku though? Cause if you haven't rails are not aware of them and has no way to communicate with sendgrid `smpt`

Comment: Yes, i did add them to heroku but the mailer still does not get sent.

Comment: What is written into the log file when you submit the form?

Comment: @Kavin Slow down.... You said "there are no errors" -- but clearly there must be, since `@invite.save` is failing. One of the first things you need to learn in coding is how to debug the project. Try following the advice above -- Put `binding.pry` into that file, try submitting the form locally, and check what `@invite.errors` is.

Comment: Do you have `:email` in your `user_params` and in your `users` table?

Answer (score 1):

My guess the invite is not being saved because you have a `belongs_to :user` relationship. Since rails 5 this is by default required. This means that *either* you have to set the `user_id` before saving, or specify it is optional.

Do not set it the user-id the form (in a hidden field), because this enables tampering (e.g. someones edits the form before submitting it).

So in your controller you can do something like

```
@invite = Invite.new(invite_params)
@invite.user_id = current_user.id 
if @invite.save ...
```

or, if the `user` is not really required you could also adapt your model

```
belongs_to :user, optional: true
```